# How to hide rows in Python dash datatable?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashboard where dash_table rows should get visible based on a dropdown value. So I want to hide the rows which doesn't match with the selected dropdown value. How to do this?

Comment: What version of python are you using? What context can you provide about your environment (such as this is a web API, a command line script, etc)? 

Are you using any libraries such as numpy or pandas?
https://numpy.org/
https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @kydreth - I am using Python3. Yes I am using Pandas and working on a jupyter notebook.

Comment: please share your code in your notebook so we can reproduce from your environment

Answer (score 0):

Plotly dash is great to use!
I assume you have the dropdown setup correctly.
Your activity here will happen in the callback function.
Ensure that you are passing the dropdown value to the callback function and use that within the function to filter the data on your dashboard figure (graph, table etc. whatever it is)
Then you can return the figure and it should update in the figure when you choose a dropdown value!

You should share some code next time so it is easier for people to help you :)